# Проблема с загрузкой данных в Tableview через сервер Parse?

Tags: swift, header, uitableview, parse.com

Мужики столкнулся с проблемой.Значит у меня есть viewController c tableViewCell. Создал я массив для PFObjecta

```
>  var userInformation = [InfoMy]()
```

Пытаюсь его указать в секции Header, у меня она одна.Не выдает.На форумах мне подсказали надо задать таким методом .Я конечно по указывал все данные в хедере и ячейках.Но загрузка данных не идет.Может как то для headera надо указать count...?

```
> var detailUserInfo = InfoMy()
```

Когда я указываю для Cell  userinformation.count .Загрузка данных в ячейки идет, а вот хедер молчит полностью пустой.Очень долго мучаюсь, помогите кто нибудь.Очень буду благодарен.
Вот мой код:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import Parse

class InfoViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{


    var userInformation = [InfoMy]()
    var detailUserInfo = InfoMy()


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detailUserInfo.fetchInBackground()



        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.universalColorYellow


        let sendButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 9, height: 12))
        sendButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "send"), for: .normal)

        sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessage), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sendButton)

        let smileButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 9, height: 12))
        smileButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "smile1"), for: .normal)
        smileButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "like2"), for: .selected)
        smileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftNavigationLikeButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: smileButton)


        //title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "HeaderViewProfileMy", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "ContactTableViewCell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 280
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

         loadMatchSoccer()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let image = UIImage(named: "forecast2")
        imageView.image = image

        navigationItem.titleView = imageView


    }



    @objc func leftNavigationLikeButton() {

        let header = ContactTableViewCell()
        let qwery = InfoMy(withoutDataWithClassName: "InfoMy", objectId: "PIorJ43dRq")
        var countLike = qwery.likeCount
        countLike += 1
        qwery.setObject(countLike, forKey: "likeCount")


        qwery.saveInBackground {  (object, error) in
            if  error == nil {
             print("error")
            } else {
                header.likeCountProfile?.text = "\(self.detailUserInfo.likeCount)"
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }

        }


    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "BRAVOBET", message: "Настройте вашу почту на телефоне", preferredStyle: .alert)

       // alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Да", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ОК", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func sendMessage() {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }

    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["a.ilyin007@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Укажите вашу тему вопроса")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Напишите свой вопрос, в течении 24ч. я Вам  отвечу!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return 1


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 300
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ContactTableViewCell") as! ContactTableViewCell

        header.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)

        header.nameUserProfile.text = detailUserInfo.name
        header.likeCountProfile?.text = "\(detailUserInfo.likeCount)"
        header.sendMessageCount.text = "\(detailUserInfo.messangeCount)"

        if  header.userMyFoto.image != nil {
            header.userMyFoto.image = UIImage(named: "avatar-pic")
        }

       detailUserInfo.imageProfile.getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
            header.userMyFoto.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
        }


        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let infoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "infoCell") as! InfoTableViewCell

        infoCell.titleProfile.text = "Профиль"
        infoCell.infogdevice.text = detailUserInfo.myinfo

        return infoCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func loadMatchSoccer() {


        let qwery = InfoMy.query() as! PFQuery<InfoMy>

        qwery.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.userInformation = object!



                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            } else {
                print(error!)

            }
        }



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так (замените text на свою info):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let labelRect = CGRect(x: 15, y: tableView.sectionHeaderHeight - 14, width: 300, height: 14)
    let label = UILabel(frame: labelRect)

    label.text = "Text"

    let viewRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.sectionHeaderHeight)
    let view = UIView(frame: viewRect)
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```

Comment: Так дело в том что userInformation выдает 0 values, а PFObject detailUserInfo выдает информацию.Но не отображает в ячейках.И правильно задавать var userInformation = [InfoMy]().Пожалуйста предложите че то другое.Это дело не в этом.

Comment: Вы пишите "Когда я указываю для Cell userinformation.count .Загрузка данных в ячейки идет, а вот хедер молчит полностью пустой." Я понял так, что не выводятся данные в заголовок секции TableView, поэтому предложил другой способ. Так выводятся данные в таблицу или нет? Кроме того, поправьте вызов super во viewDidAppear, у Вас там viewWillAppear указан.

Comment: Спасибо поправлю.Нет в Хедере не идет загрузка.Я думаю это зависит , я не правильно задал код для загрузки данных Parse.